# Jquery, ASP.NET MVC Async task?

Tags: jquery

Simple button,
How do I disable the button immediately?
my api call is not async, but I dont want user submitting multiple requests?

Example?
 Search

```
    function GetClient() {
    $("#btnSubmitCode").prop("disabled",true);

    //Ajax call here

//takes a few seconds to go and get info from api
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use ajax call setup for disable the button.

```
$.post(your_api_url, { data,
    beforeSend: function() {
        $("#btnSubmitCode").prop("disabled",true);
    },
    error: function() {
        $("#btnSubmitCode").prop("disabled",false);
    },
    success: function(data) {
        $("#btnSubmitCode").prop("disabled",false);    
    }
});
```